Trying to clear unused Wordpress input variables
A site came to us after a long existence outside of our control, so I'm not sure what may have been done with it in the past.  Despite WP Engine having their default PHP max input variables set to 100000 we are unable to edit the menu.
I duplicated the site and remoived all menus, unused plugins, etc. and then cleared all caches.  I am still able to create or edit menus. I'm not familiar enough with how these are stored. Is there a preferred way to locate and remove these?
